# ¿Cómo imprimir imagen sobre otra recortándola?

Tags: jquery, css, html5, css3, imagen

Tengo el siguiente código HTML y CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <title>Imagen</title>
<style>

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.primary {
  position: absolute;
}

.secondary {
    background-image: url(A001.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-blend-mode: screen;
    background-color: #252222;
    opacity: .4;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="plantilla.png" class="primary">
  <div class="secondary">
  </div>




</body>
</html>
```

Eso da como resultado la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, ¿cómo puedo hacer para que quede de esta forma?:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O ¿cual tecnología me recomiendan que pueda hacer ese recorte del diseño sobre el sueter?

Saludos.

Comment: Buena pregunta. De momento yo no sé si es posible, pero se me ocurre otra manera: y si recortas la imagen de la pantera con la forma del sueter, utilizando photoshop por ejemplo? Así luego sólo tienes que mostrar esa imagen sobre el sueter y no tienes que manipularla con código.

Comment: Puedes utilizar clip-path de CSS3. Acá te dejo el link de un tutorial: https://www.programandoamedianoche.com/2019/09/propiedad-clip-path/.

Comment: Hola @Gustavo Cantero ya vi la opción del clip-path en css pero no se como hacer para que funcione con una imagen como la que tengo de sueter, funciona bien pero con formas como un circulo o un rectangulo.

Comment: @Jemonge esa idea ya la contenple, pero no me sirve si llego a pasar todo el código a php y que me traiga el diseño desde la base de datos, la idea seria subir cada diseño plano en forma de cuadro y luego que se imprima en el sueter pero sin quitarle la forma de sueter, solo que imprima el diseño y ya.

Comment: @estrada, en el estilo de la imagen del tigre deberías agregar un clip-path: polygon con la forma del sweater.

Comment: listo lo agregue de la siguiente forma: clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 80% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%); y quedo bien pero todavia se ve el polygon como figura principal, como podria hacer para darle la forma del sueter?

Comment: @estrada a lo que veo, tienes que darle la forma del sueter agregando pares de puntos que indican su posición X, Y. En este enlace puedes ver más cómo funciona clip-path y manipularlo sobre la imagen para darle la forma que necesitas. https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: @Jemonge muchas gracias :) me sirvio tu ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependería de cuales son las imágenes fuente exactamente, pero en realidad lo que tienes que explorar son los blending modes de CSS.

El opacity utilliza el blending mode normal por default, esto es, simplemente transparencia.

Pero existen algunos otros. Cuando el objeto del fondo es claro, digamos una sudadera blanca, y la impresión es con tinta transparente, el que te conviene usar es el multiply.

Para este caso tal vez lighten o screen, tendrás que probar con tus imágenes fuente.

```
.secondary
    {mix-blend-mode: screen;}
```

No todos los navegadores aceptan estos blending modes.